# fatal error: string: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c++, string, g++, header-files

I 've been struggling for more than 3 hours but cannot find a solution.
A simple helloworld program is running nicely and I can get the output,

```
 #include<iostream>
    #include<string>

    using namespace std;
    int main(){
       string s;
       cout<<"hello world";
    }
```

> But for the My Sudoku Project I have the following user defined header
>   files, SudokuSolver.h, Matrix.h, Cell.h, Pos.h, Error.h, Exception.h and
>   their corresponding .cpp files.
>
> And `ExampleProgram.cpp` uses these header files, to solve a Sudoku.

(All the .h and .cpp files are in a same folder.)

I have included  `using namespace std;` and I included the string as `#include <string>`.
in each header file, wherever I used string.h. But even though I am getting the `fatal error: string: No such file or directory compilation terminated.` when I run as

g++  ExampleProgram.cpp SudokuSolver.h Cell.h Error.h Pos.h Matrix.h

**When I compile the ExampleProgram.cpp** as

```
 g++ -c ExampleProgram.cpp SudokuSolver.h
 Cell.h Error.h Pos.h Matrix.h
```

I am getting no error.

**When I run the ExampleProgram.cpp** using `./a.out` I am not getting the output for my sudoku solver. Rather I am getting the output of my previously runned helloworld program. It shows my `ExampleProgram.cpp` has not successfully compiled. But as previously said

```
g++ -c ExampleProgram.cpp  SudokuSolver.h 
    Cell.h Error.h Pos.h Matrix.h
```

doesn't give any error.

This is my output:

```
[fosslab@fosslab SudokuSolver]$ g++ -c Error.h
[fosslab@fosslab SudokuSolver]$ g++ -c Exception.h
[fosslab@fosslab SudokuSolver]$ g++ -c Matrix.h
[fosslab@fosslab SudokuSolver]$ g++ -c Cell.h
[fosslab@fosslab SudokuSolver]$ g++ -c Pos.h
[fosslab@fosslab SudokuSolver]$ g++ -c SudokuSolver.h
[fosslab@fosslab SudokuSolver]$ g++ -c ExampleProgram.cpp SudokuSolver.h Excepti
on.h Cell.h Error.h Pos.h Matrix.h                                             
[fosslab@fosslab SudokuSolver]$ ./a.out
hello world[fosslab@fosslab SudokuSolver]$
```

Comment: You don't compile header files.

Comment: @trojanfoe  I had compiled it already.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT No, actually you never compile a header file. It's included using the include statement when you compile (actually in the preprocess stage) a .cpp file.

Comment: You shouldn't compile, header files should contain only declarations of function/class not they definitions (the only exceptions are inline  functions and templates). After you compile source files (not headers), you'll link it all and **linker** checks whether all required declarations have their correct definitions (you'll get `Unknown reference...` if they don't).

Comment: @Vyktor: You mean that they should only contain function declarations and class definitions.

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi: Yes, you do. You just happen to do it implicitly because its contents have been textually inserted into the preprocessed `.cpp` :)

Comment: @AntonGolov yes, my bad :) and macros! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, header files a meant to be *included* in the source files. Do not add them to the command line for the compiler.

Secondly, the command line argument "-c" to g++ tells g++ to not link and make an executable file, but only make an object file.

You should either do:

```
$ g++ -c ExampleProgram.cpp
$ g++ ExampleProgram.o
```

or

```
$ g++ ExampleProgram.cpp
```

In both the above cases you will get a new "a.out" executable program.

If you have several *source* files, then compile them and not the header files:

```
$ g++ -c Error.cpp
$ g++ -c Exception.cpp
$ # etc...
$ g++ -c ExampleProgram.cpp
$ g++ Error.o Exception.o ... ExampleProgram.o
```

Answer (score 3):

I know its late but my answer might help others who are facing this issue. It is quite possible that you don't have libstdc++-devel package on your system.
Please recheck. I faced the same issue and could resolve it by installing the devel package.